# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos en tablas relacionadas con inputs con pdo?

Tags: php

hola tengo una duda de como poder relacionar dos tablas para insertar registros de una tabla a otra, he buscado por varios lados y no encuentro como lo puedo hacer.
tengo dos tablas

```
-tabla 1: id_usu pk, usuario, password.
-tabla 2: id_con pk, id_usu fk, negocio, slogan, imagen, ubicacion, web, telefono. 

-id_usu  - usuario - password
-  1       jorge       123
-  2       lucia       123
-  3       luisa       123

-id_con  -  id_usu   -  negocio  - slogan  - imagen - ubicacion - web - telefono
-  1                      comex    la mejor    ../     sotelo   comex.com    457878
```

y requiero identificar que usuario ingresa cada registro por ejemplo:

```
-id_usu   -   id_usu
-  1            1
-  2            2
-  3            3
```

uso session_start(), y ya tengo en funcionamiento mi conexion en la tabla 1 se ingresan mis usuarios perfectamente pero en la tabla 2 no se ingresa nada a menos que le elimine el campo id_usu.
este es mi codigo de login.php

```
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO rusa (usuario, password, checkbox) 
        VALUES (:usuario, :password, :checkbox)');
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':usuario' => $usuario,
        ':password' => $password,
        ':checkbox' => $checkbox)); 
    $statement =$conexion->prepare("SELECT @@identity AS id");
    $statement->execute();
    $resultado = $statement->fetchAll();
    $id = 0;
    foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
    }
```

este es mi codigo de contenido.php

```
    $negocio = $_POST['negocio'];
$slogan = $_POST['slogan'];
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
$web = $_POST['web'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

$errores = '';

if (empty($negocio)) {
    $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
} else {
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anunciate', 'root', '');

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO contenido (id_con, id_usu, negocio, slogan, imagen, ubicacion, web, telefono) VALUES (:id_con, :id_usu, :negocio, :slogan, :imagen, :ubicacion, :web, :telefono)');
    $statement->bindParam(':id_con', $id_con);
    $statement->bindParam(':id_usu', $id);
```

les agradeceria mucho si me ayudaran.

Comment: ¿Donde esta definida la variable `$id_con`? Entiendo que la tabla `contenido` tiene como `PK` la columna `id_con`. Me parece que ese es un error, porque deberías tener como `PK` las columas `id_con` y `id_usu` de lo contrario te va a dar error si intentas guardar 2 veces el mismo `id_con` para 2 usuarios diferentes.

Comment: Tabla 1 id_usu y tabla 2 id_con son autoincrementables, tengo entendido que para una relación de tablas debe ser una pk con una fk es por eso que los tengo así

Comment: Si sólo permite guardar cuando quitas id_usu es porque la FK lo impide y estás enviando un valor que no está en el campo `rusa.id_usu`. Has revisado qué va en ese campo cuando lo intentas insertar? Has validado que el registro en la tabla 1 ya esté cuando intentas insertar en tabla 2?